# .htaccess not get variablas that not set on external

Tags: .htaccess

i have to set category by type  like `getcategorytype1`, `getcategorytype2` and `getcategorytype3`

i write code in `.htacces`

```
RewriteRule ^getcategorytype1/(.*) category.php?getcategory=type1&q=$1
RewriteRule ^getcategorytype2/(.*) category.php?getcategory=type2&q=$1
RewriteRule ^getcategorytype3/(.*) category.php?getcategory=type3&q=$1
```

if i pass url `mysite.com/categorytype1/` it work fine to get `getcategory=type1`

but if i want to pass other variables like `mysite.com/categorytype1/?var=123` than `var` is not getting

how it possible to get extra variables ?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa Btw., you could do this with just one rule instead of three if you matched the number part with an according pattern as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse request through ...

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^getcategorytype1/(.*) category.php?getcategory=type1&q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

QSA is the solution for you